# How does one become a mathematician?

Tags: advice, career-development

I mean how someone goes from a student to become a teacher or a professor ? What is that state feel like ? Are you confident of the knowledge you have conquered over the years ?or there is part of doubt in there ?

I am current in the 3rd year out of 4 to get my degree, and I am struggling to learn the subjects to the fullest, always questions about things that confuse me and  I can't answer , I can't solve problems with confidence (a lot of times I can't solve them at all), I don't have much confidence about my solution etc. I have a feeling that even if I get my degree those doubts and confusion  won't go away like that, if there is someone who felt that way their opinion and point of view are more that welcome . You can imagine you are giving advice to your old self , an advise you never got but you needed.

For example because you did good on your finals doesn't mean you know abstract algebra , it's like the piano, you can't call your self a pianist because you know how to play well 5-10 songs. So when someone can be called a mathematician ? Or even that at least he knows abstract  algebra. Also,  I can observe that my knowledge on statistics and probabilities are a bit weaker over the pure math like real analysis number theory etc(because i study them more and give them more attention). Does every professor know deeply all the subjects ?

Comment: Most mathematicians nowadays do not know all subjects deeply

Comment: It's probably a better idea to talk to someone who knows you in the math faculty at your university, than to solicit advice from random strangers on the internet.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You can’t really call the people on this place “random” when it comes to advice about careers in mathematics. We do have tags for this sort of questions after all.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson I don't have that intimacy with my professors , what exactly i suppose to do write an email about what ? wouldn't that be strange to do ?

Comment: [This video of Feynman might encourage you.](https://youtu.be/lytxafTXg6c)

Comment: @Shaun this video  was very inspiring to me  i really thank you for that .

Comment: You're welcome, @PetrosK.

Comment: @k.stm Tags do not really legitimize content that isn’t on topic.  We also have *flags* for this stuff: namely *seeking personal advice* and *opinion based*.

Comment: @rschwieb I wasn’t making a point on whether the question is well-put or reasonable to bring up here. I only wanted to remark that calling the people here “random strangers” with respect to this matter may be selling this site short. And the thing about the tags: I meant, they are here for good reason – there are people here who are in good position to give advice on careers in mathematics.

Comment: @k.stm the people on this site are random when it comes to knowing anything about OP. The more one knows about OP, the better the advice one can give, and those who have had OP in their classes know more about OP than the random people on this site. Many math departments also have someone designated as Undergraduate Advisor or some such title, whose job consists, in part, of giving good advice to people like OP. And, no, Petros, I don't think it would be strange to make an appointment to talk to someone in your department about your questions.

Comment: @ I read your comment and I can't argue with that, you have a point here. But because of Covid-19 I can't talk personally with my professors, only through e-mail, and that's why I sought help here. As soon as I can meet with my professors I will contact them about that, thanks for letting me know to do that, isn't  as strange as I thought.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That people here don’t personally know the questioner is already said with the word *strangers*, no need for topping that with *random*. Anyway, I’m done argueing words here. As I said, I only wanted to make a point about not selling this site short. That’s all.

Comment: Is it possible, Petros, to talk with a professor through Skype or some other software?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson i am not sure about that, most of my professors now don't have online office hours, so I will have to ask them through an e-mail if we could talk through Skype. But I believe it would be better to do this on person it would help me more with my anxiety about it. Also, I am not in a rush i just need to have this talk by the end of spring of 2021, so I can also decide what subject should I follow :abstract algebra or analysis because I really like them both and I need someone who knows these two to guide me. I may even ask here if I don't find a way, thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that I don't know you, nor does anyone else on this forum probably, I cannot say whether your doubts are justified or not. I can only share my limited experience.

Almost my entire (short) mathematical career was centered around algebraic number theory. I've taught a few courses in abstract algebra over the years, from group theory to algebraic geometry. My knowledge of statistics and real analysis is *extremely* limited, somewhere around second-year level. Certainly nowhere near research level, I have no deep understanding of anything related to those subjects.

I started to gain confidence in my ability as a mathematician once I became a teaching assistant, when I got to see the work of dozens and dozens of other students. Seeing their perspectives, their approaches, and hearing their questions greatly broadened my own mathematical toolbox, and it also made clear to me that my mathematical abilities were at least above average.

At first, teaching (tutorials, as a TA) was quite frightening and I did not think I was fit for the job. After a few months of weekly tutorials I was able to answer most questions quite comfortably, and deliver coherent and somewhat interactive lectures (of 20-30 minutes). After about a year I was comfortable discussing problems instead of simply answering them, and comfortable admitting that I didn't know an answer, and maybe even investigating the question together with the students. Around this time I started considering myself to be an actual teacher.

Comment: your answer was very reassuring to me, i dont have someone to talk about this things and this was very helpful to me , thanks for the time you 
dedicated to write this .

Comment: I second this answer. I got my PhD a couple years ago, and I am only an "expert" in one or two very specialized areas. I assume you are an undergaduate? An undergraduate education only gives you a broad overview of some basic concepts in various areas of math. You will not get a good idea of what it's like to be a mathematician until you are in grad school for a few years. At that point, you will get some experience doing research and teaching.